# How to modify OS contextual action bar for text selection in EditText?

Tags: android

When selecting text in EditText menu appears with some predefined options like Copy, Cut or Paste. I know that I can extend this menu with some custom actions for particular EditText in my app but my question is:

Is it possible to add option to this predfined OS menu so that it will be available to all applications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this page regarding how to use the contextual action mode: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB